JavaScript: animate z-index of an element with element animate() method
On a web page, I have an element I would like to animate its z-index.
Here is my code:
myElement.animate({
    opacity: [0.1, 1.0, 0.1, 0],
    background: ["red", "green", "red"],
    z-index: [0, 128, 0]
}, {
    fill: 'forwards',
    timeline: new ViewTimeline({
        subject: animationTrigger

    }),
    rangeStart: {rangeName: 'entry', offset: CSS.percent(4)},
    rangeEnd: {rangeName: 'exit', offset: CSS.percent(64)},
});

I have tried z-index, zindex, but nothing works.
Apparently, I am using the wrong property name.
Any help or a hint will be appreciated.

See also

Stupid question, but your code has a syntax error, is this the typo or the actual issue? did you try surrounding the z-index property name in quotes?

@KrzysztofKrzeszewski,
Yes, I have tried z-index, zindex and "z-index" .

@James Thank you for the hint. I have seen the issue already. It does work in my case, since I have several overlapping elements. What I need is to change the z-index of the element at the of the animation.

try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755896/jquery-animate-z-index-not-working

You need to use camel case for the prop name z-index to zIndex see keyframe attributes

@James, thanks a lot! This did the trick.
